# how to refresh web page using java code?

Tags: java, ant

I am creating a web page for an application and I need to refresh the page to see the changes.
how can I do it using Java or even ant script will do??

Thanks in advance

Comment: *If you're using Servlets*, you can just redirect it to that page again.

Comment: Why not add a `meta` tag in the `<head>`, like `<head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/></head>`, that will suffice, now page will refresh every 10 seconds.

Comment: Are you asking how to make Java *make your browser* refresh, or do you merely wish to fetch a URL in Java?

Comment: Okay, web page is developed using - JSP ?

Comment: I want Java code to refresh my web page.

Comment: method 1 would be getting the browser window, and sending keystroke f5. Other method would be a webdriver like selenium.

Comment: I am creating a job in Jenkins web page using CLI options. I need to refresh this Jenkins page in order to see the job created. how can I do it using Java or ant script. I only pass the URL.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Servlet, in your service method use code like this.

```
          response.setHeader("Refresh", "10; URL=http://localhost:9090/J2EE_Exercise/index.html");
```

It will refresh my page in 10 seconds, and redirect it in "index.html" page which is the index page of my project named "J2EE_Exercise".